# Are the Black-Scholes equation models still considered accurate predictors for asset pricing?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, soft-question, finance, stochastic-differential-equations

Sorry if this equation is not phrase in precise mathematical form. I am open to suggestions to improve the explanation, and I have tried to formulate the problem as precisely as I could.

I was talking to a friend--postdoc in PDEs--today and he was asking me about obtaining some Yahoo data on stock prices for his students. He explained that he had some students working on stock price data and he was looking for software packages/libraries for time series analysis--like ARIMA, GARCH, ARMA, ETS, etc.

I told him that as far as I remember, most many models to stock prices or asset prices use stochastic differential equation like the Black-Scholes models. So I was asking if he actually needed like a stochastic differential equation solver, rather than a time series package.

He said something that surprised me. He said that many people used to use Black-Scholes models, but implied that they are not used as much any more. He basically said that many people lost money using these models.

I myself don't work in mathematical finance or in banking at all. However, I was unaware of any major critiques of stochastic differential equations and their applications. From a formal perspective, I imagine that these SDE models have a set of parameters (means, variances, etc.) that users can tune against some data using an optimization method. I am not sure what optimization would make sense, I can imagine approximate bayes or something, could work, but there are probably a million choices. So is the claim of a bad fit, mean that the error between the model predictions and the ground truth data too high, or perhaps changing over time, etc. Also, are there a different set of finance models being used as replacements for Black-Scholes?

Comment: This depends on context.  Black Scholes is fully accurate given it's assumptions (frictionless hedging, constant volatility, etc.)  Other models weaken those strong assumptions, but of course they have flaws as well.  [Quant Stack exchange](https://quant.stackexchange.com) might be a better place for such questions.

Comment: @lulu thanks for the response. Yeah, my background is statistics and ML, but I also know PDEs. So I can understand that problems occur when reality violates the assumptions of the model. There is also model drift, missing data, etc. But there are ways to deal with these issues. I was asking in the Math.SE because I wanted to identify any mathematical critiques to the approach? Like is the underlying model flawed in some way, or is it just that the model just cannot converge asymptotically to the data?

Comment: @krishnab : constant variance is viewed as a restrictive assumption by many so people have built option models that try to incorporate stochastic volatility.

Comment: @markleeds yes, that makes sense. So you are basically defining a hyperparameter distribution over the model variance parameter. Then you can draw a hyperparameter variance value at each time step and then a draw from the noise distribution given that random variance. There are many ways to do this, whether that is drawing a new hyperparameter at each timestep or ensembling a bunch of simulations where the variance parameter is drawn once for each simulation. That all is understandable.

Comment: Black, Scholes and Merton did not receive the Nobel prize for accurately predicting asset prices. If this is you and your friends goal I recommend to put on a [Swabian housewife](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q19307530) hat and consider the following: is it possible in a zero sum game (Gordon Gecko) that *everybody* makes money? The answer to this will also be the answer to the question if there can possibly be a model that accurately predicts stock prices.

Comment: @KurtG. Haha, if I found a model to perfectly predict stock prices, I would be doing other things than posting on SE :). But the real point is whether the model is externally valid, meaning that the BSM model gives accurate estimates for the mean and variance of the asset price at some time in the future--using test cases that were not part of the calibration data for estimating model parameters. I have seen references to a Non-Equilibrium Skewness model, as an alternative to BSM, but I don't follow the field closely enough to know if NES models are replacing BSM, etc., especially in research.

Comment: Hi Krishnab: I guess you could view it as defining a hyperparameter. You build a model ( which includes parameters ) for the assumed volatility process and incorporate into the BS model. Note that you're not using BS to predict the mean and variance of the stock price. You're using it to calculate the value of a call ( or put ) on the stock given the price and the strike and the time to expiration..